# How to hide text before video ends with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have video and text that I am displaying when user clicks play button (4 seconds). So my code looks like this:

```
$('video').on('play', function (e) {
      $('#showText').delay(4000).show(0); 
    });
```

What I am trying to achieve is hide this text (#showText) 5 seconds before the end of the video. I didn’t find any solution for this, so if anybody can help with this I’ll be more than thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you can use the standard events associated with media elements. Specifically `play` and `timeupdate`. The former you've already covered. The latter fires as the playback progresses. You can use it to check the current position and determine if it's less than 5 seconds from the end, like this:

```js
var $showText = $('#showText');

$('video').on({
  play: function() {
    $showText.delay(4000).show(0);
  },
  timeupdate: function(e) {
    if ((this.duration - this.currentTime) < 5 && $showText.is(':visible'))
      $showText.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#showText {
  display: none;
}

video {
  height: 175px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="showText">Lorem ipsum</p>
<video autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [video.js](https://github.com/videojs) to get **length** of video then you can hide any element **at any second before video is ending**

```
var myPlayer = videojs('example_video_1'); //defining videojs
<video id="example_video_1" data-setup="{}" controls="">
<source src="my-source.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>  //end defining videojs

$('#showText').delay(4000).show(0); 
var lengthOfVideo = myPlayer.duration(); // length Of Video in seconds
 $(#showText).oneTime(lengthOfVideo-5, function() {  // 5 second before video ends
    $("showText").hide();
 });
```